# Need to rank all variable for Spearman's rho?

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho

I have decided to use spearman's rho for the correlation of my paper since whatever I do with my dependent variable, it doesn't turn normal. 
I read that spearman (also Kendall) can be used with interval, ordinal, or nominal data. I just want to make sure. Is it okay for me to not rank the independent variable? Or even I don't rank both variables? Or must I rank all variables to use spearman's rank correlation?

Comment: Please rethink the first step: because the dependent variable reflects the distributions of the explanatory variables as well as the random error, when the explanatory variables are not Normally distributed (for instance, when they are nominal), we *expect* the response not to be Normal.  There is *nothing* about regression that assumes the dependent variable has a Normal distribution.  You might still have a problem, but this isn't the reason for it.

Comment: Building on whuber's comment, remember that the common normality assumption is linear regression concerns the error term, not the data. For instance, do a simulation in R: `set.seed(2019); x <- rchisq(1000,5); err <- rnorm(length(x)); y <- x + err; boxplot(y)`.

Comment: If you are using Spearman's *rho*, then, yes, you want to use the ranks of both variables.  You *could* correlate the ranks of one variable to the untransformed values of another variable, but your audience might have trouble interpreting the result or understanding why you did that. ... I also have to object to the idea that these correlation techniques can be used for nominal data, except in the case where there are only two groups in the nominal variable.